# How can you remove superset lists from a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a list of lists in Python like the following:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3],[2,4,3],[4,5],[5]]
```

I want to remove all the inner lists that are a superset (a list that contain all the elements of another list, but with additional elements) of another inner list. For the example above, removing the supersets should result in the following:

```
[[2,3],[5]]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set can only be a subset of another if it is smaller, thus by iterating over the sets in ascending order of size, we can check each element against the previously found minimal subsets to know if it is a minimal subset.

```
def get_minimal_subsets(sets):
    sets = sorted(map(set, sets), key=len)
    minimal_subsets = []
    for s in sets:
        if not any(minimal_subset.issubset(s) for minimal_subset in minimal_subsets):
            minimal_subsets.append(s)

    return minimal_subsets

l = [[1,2,3],[2,3],[2,4,3],[4,5],[5]]

print(get_minimal_subsets(l))  # [{5}, {2, 3}]
```

Comment: Your code is nice and clean. If you look at my answer, you can remove a loop of minimal_subsets per iteration by removing the matching supersets every iteration. My assumption is that this is more performant than the cost of slicing each loop, but I haven't timed it to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up with the same idea as @Olivier Melançon. You can use ascending order to throw away subsets and have this run in O(n^2) * O(subset calculation).

```
input = [[1,2,3],[2,3],[2,4,3],[4,5],[5]]
sets = [set(x) for x in input]
sets.sort(key=len)

subsets = []
while sets != []:
    cur = sets[0]
    subsets.append(cur)
    sets = [x for x in sets[1:] if not cur <= x]

output = [list(x) for x in subsets]
print(output)
```

Comment: Instead of slicing, you should sort in reverse order and pop the last element which is O(1). First: `sets.sort(key=len, reverse=True)` Then `cur = sets.pop(); subsets.append(cur)`. This allows to remove the slicing from the list comprehension: `sets = [x for x in sets if not cur <= x]`.

Comment: How would you do it the other way: keep supersets, but throw away subsets? I do it with a lambda function but I get a huge performance hit as the main list gets bigger: `clean_list = filter(lambda f: not any(set(f) < set(g) for g in main_list), main_list)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
d = [[1,2,3],[2,3],[2,4,3],[4,5],[5]]
new_d = [i for i in d if not any(all(c in i for c in b) and len(b) < len(i) for b in d)]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3], [5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
super=[[1,2,3],[2,3],[2,4,3],[4,5],[5]]
subset=[s for s in super if not any(set(s).issuperset(set(i)) and len(s)>len(i) for i in super)]
```

Output:

```
>>> subset
[[2, 3], [5]]
```